# How to set the Laravel middleware order of execution?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

The [Laravel 5 documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#controller-middleware) describes two ways of assigning **Middleware**:

1. Assign middleware to the controller's route.
2. Specify middleware within your controller's constructor.

However, I realised that any code written in the controllers `__construct()` function will run before the **Middleware**, even if the **Middleware** is declared on the first line of the controller's `__construct` function.

I found a [bug report](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8558) for a similar issue in the Laravel github repository. However a collaborator closed the issue stating "This is the expected behaviour.".

I am thinking that `middleware` should be "layers" outside the application, while the `__construct` function is part of the application.

Why is the `__construct` function executed before the middleware (given it is declared before middleware runs)? and why this is expected?

Comment: I just did a few tests to confirm. If you want the middleware to execute before your controllers `__construct()` you need to assign the middleware to the route. Otherwise it will always be executed at the end of the `__construct()` even if assigned on the very first line of the `construct()`.

Comment: I created a quick example to outline what you are describing, feel free to add it to your question. https://www.notehub.org/2015/6/26/say-we-have-a-controller----welcomecontr

Comment: @Jeemusu Thanks for your comment. Yup, I also found out this difference between the two ways of assigning middleware. However, by placing the middleware at the end of execution flow in the constructor, is it against the Request Lifecycle (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/lifecycle), since Dispatch Request should be at the end?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The application logic resides in the controller's methods. So basically application lives in the controller's methods, not in the whole controller itself.

Middleware runs BEFORE the request enters the respective controller method. And thus, this is always OUTSIDE the real application. No controller method is executed unless all the Middlewares are passing the request.

The `$this->middleware("My\Middleware");` statements that you put in the controller constructor, REGISTERS the `My\Middleware` for checking before the request enters the application.

If you see the code of a middleware and
if the request is passing, then we send it to the next middleware using the `$next($request);` statement. This allows multiple middlewares to be executed for a single request. Now, if Laravel run the middleware right at the `$this->middleware(...);` statement, Laravel would probably not be able to know which middleware should be next checked.

So, Laravel solves this by registering all the middlewares first, then passing the request through all the middlewares one by one.

Comment: an interesting case with this it where the middleware runs in respect to the constructor.  Any global middleware actually seems to run *before* the constructor, while any local middleware runs after the constructor.  This inconsistency has caused me confusion and troubles in the past.

Comment: so what runs first cause the answer is unclear for me 
i expect it to be as follow 
**group route** => **route specified** (by array order) then `controler construct` . is this true

Comment: I too am still mystified on how laravel decides which order to run them in.  Is it alphabetical?

Comment: well right now in 5.7, even the global middleware is running AFTER the controller's construct!

Comment: I don't see how this answer addresses anything related to the order of execution of the middlewares.

Answer (score 19):

Another answer to cover another use case to that question

If it's related to the order between middleware it self

> You can update the $middlewarePriority in your App\Kernel.

Comment: This should be accepted answer, such this way i can order the execution of the middlewares

Comment: Laravel 5: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/middleware#sorting-middleware ;

Laravel 8 (current): https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware#sorting-middleware

Answer (score 14):

## Set Middleware Priority in `App\Http\Kernel`

For example, here I need my custom auth middleware to run first (before substitute bindings), so I unshift it onto the stack:

```php
public function __construct(Application $app, Router $router)
{
    /**
     * Because we are using a custom authentication middleware,
     * we want to ensure it's executed early in the stack.
     */
    array_unshift($this->middlewarePriority, MyCustomApiAuthMiddleware::class);

    parent::__construct($app, $router);
}
```

Alternatively, you could override that entire priority structure if you needed explicit control (not recommended because you'll have to pay closer attention during upgrades to see if the framework changes). Specific to this issue is the `SubstituteBindings` class that handles route model binding, so just make sure your auth middleware comes sometime before that.

```php
/**
 * The priority-sorted list of middleware.
 *
 * Forces the listed middleware to always be in the given order.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    \App\Http\Middleware\MyCustomApiAuthMiddleware::class
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
    \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
];
```

Answer (score 4):

They updated the order of execution between `middlewares`, `controller` and controller's construct.

Previously it was:

```
1. The global middleware pipeline
2. The route middleware pipeline
3. The controller middleware pipeline
```

Now its:

```
1. The global middleware pipeline
2. Controller's Construct
3. The route & controller middlewares
```

Read more here:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/execution-order-in-controllers-constructor-whit-middleware
https://laravel-news.com/controller-construct-session-changes-in-laravel-5-3