# Laravel 5.1 view composer initiates before middleware

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a simple web application with Laravel 5.1 and my development environment is Homestead.

I have a view composer to pass `Auth::user()` data to admin panel related views automatically. Most general admin panel pages (Dashboard, Settings etc.) uses `AdminController`, and it extends Laravel's `Controller`. Specific admin panel pages (Users, Orders etc.) has their own controllers (`Admin\UsersController`, `Admin\OrdersController` respectively), which are extends `AdminController`.

No any middleware registered in `routes` for admin panel related routes, instead `AdminController` loads the `auth` middleware (which checks if registered user tries to load the page). And no other controller that extends `AdminController` overrides the constructor.

My problem is that if user is not logged in and tries to load an admin panel page (doesn't matter which one; Dashboard, Settings, Users, Orders - because the view composer called for every single one to pass `Auth::user()` data) there is no warning says "You are not authorized." or no redirection to login page, just an exception thrown which says `Auth::user()` is `null`.

Doesn't the `auth` middleware called first? If not what should I do to prevent the exception to be thrown (`return`ing from view composer is not an elegant solution for my point of view by the way)?

Thanks in advance.

---

Addendum

- `AdminController`

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  use App\Http\Requests;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

  class AdminController extends Controller
  {
      public function __construct()
      {
          // After middlewares
          $this->middleware("auth");
          $this->middleware("admin");

          // Before middlewares
          $this->middleware("no-cache");
      }

      /**
       * Display a listing of the resource.
       *
       * @return Response
       */
      public function index()
      {
          return view("admin.index");
      }
  }
  ```
- `Admin\OrdersController`

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  use App\Http\Requests;
  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

  use App\Order;

  class OrdersController extends Controller
  {
      /**
       * Display a listing of the resource.
       *
       * @return Response
       */
      public function index()
      {
          $orders = Order::with("address")->get();

          return view("admin.orders.index")->with("orders", $orders);
      }
  }
  ```
- `ComposerServiceProvider`

  ```
  <?php

  namespace App\Providers;

  use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

  use Auth;

  class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
  {
      /**
       * Bootstrap the application services.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function boot()
      {
          view()->composer("layouts.admin.default", function ($view) {
              $admin = Auth::user();

              $view->with([
                  "admin" => $admin,
                  "picture" => $admin->pictures[0]
              ]);
          });
      }

      /**
       * Register the application services.
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function register()
      {
          //
      }
  }
  ```

Note: `ComposerServiceProvider` is registered in `config/app.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Admin\OrdersController` extends `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`, when it should extend `App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController`. That's why you are not getting a redirection.

Comment: Wow thanks for the heads-up, I missed that. But it's not the solution I was seeking for. When I try to load an admin panel page which "uses" `AdminController` (say Dashboard) I'm still facing with the peculiar problem of mine. Middlewares shouldn't be called before the view composers?

Comment: I'm not sure but, maybe it's because you are calling the middleware from the controller. I always add middlewares into the route like `Route::get('foo', ['middleware' => 'auth' /* the rest */ ]);`

Comment: Yes that will do and also stated as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065936/execution-order-of-middleware-in-laravel-5). One more question (because I feel lazy to dig into the documents right now) are middlewares written in `routes` file comma-separated?

Comment: That looks like a strange behavior but I'm sure Taylor has a reason for it. Just use route middlewares then. That solves your problem, right?

Comment: Yes it solved my problem and the answer marked as Solution. Thanks. And to answer my latest question on comments, the document says "Use an array to assign multiple middleware to the route".