# Auth::check() returns false Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I have created the routes and views needed for authentication using one simple command:

```
php artisan make:auth
```

Everything works fine login and register sections. However when I go to my controller's constructor to check if the user its logged in I always get false response; even though the user its logged in!

```
public function __construct()
{
    dd(Auth::check());

}
```

Any idea?! And yes I did `use Auth;` at the top.

Comment: Try this `\Auth::check()` instead-of  `Auth::check()`

Comment: still getting false on return

Answer (score 2):

Middleware (and therefore setting the logged in user) don't happen until **after** the controller constructor. See this related question/answer for more details:

[Laravel 5 Auth is non object in Controller construct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44056172/laravel-5-auth-is-non-object-in-controller-construct/44056292#44056292)

Answer (score 1):

Use the helper function `auth()->check()` and add

`$this->middleware('auth')` to the `function __construct()` method.

Comment: Can you insert `auth()->loginUsingId(1)` above the `auth()->check()` and see if you got true?

Comment: 1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method loginWithId does not exist.

Comment: My bad. It was `loginUsingId()`

Comment: Yes I got the user object as a return with the users info.

Comment: Then something has gone wrong with the `LoginController` and we need more information on that. And you should use the `Auth Middleware` in the construct method.